# PHP - How do I send a variable from one PHP file to another?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a two files: `index.php` and `get.php`

`index.php` is a web page, but `get.php` will not be accessed by the user as it is not indented to be a web page; it is just supposed to echo some HTML code out to be used in `index.php`.

`index.php`:

```
<?php

$id = 0;

?>
```

`get.php`:

```
...
$message_id = $message['message_id'];
```

How can I send the `$message_id` variable to the `index.php` file and store is in `$id`?

Comment: sounds like you want a simple include()

Comment: in `index.php` write `include( 'get.php' );`

Answer (score 1):

You Can use Session variable inside php tags on your page get.php
Like this

```
// Set session variables
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["msg"] =  $message['message_id'];
?>
```

Now you Can Access this on index.php and store it in $id variable like this

```
<?php
session_start();
$id = $_SESSION["msg"];
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to "send" files from one PHP page to another. However, you could store the variables in a common place accessible to both files.

For eg.

1. You could use Sessions.

Add a

```
session_start();
```

at the start of both files. Then, in get.php, save the value in $_SESSION array, like:

```
$_SESSION['message_id'] = $message['message_id'];
```

Then, in index.php, access it from the $_SESSION array, like:

```
$message_id = $_SESSION['message_id'];
```

2. You could use the include command

In index.php, simply add

```
include 'get.php';
```

at the top. With this, all variables/functions in get.php will be accessible from index.php.

3. You could write an API

If you don't want the get.php to be directly accessible from index.php, you could make another file, say get_message_id.php, and put in the following code:

```
include 'get.php';

$password = $_POST['password'];

if($password == '<have predefined password here>')
  echo $message_id;
```

This is a primitive way to ensure that only you have access to the $message_id. Simply do a [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php) request to this page, passing your predefined password as Http post, and it will return the message_id to you.